# VBA to ouput odbc connection to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, db2, odbc, vba

I'm working on some vba that will vary an odbc connection string based on selected report and filters in a workbook.  The core of the vba works absolutely fine but now I want to do the following:

1. Create a new worksheet
2. Run the odbc connection (called "ODBC_RUN_REPORT" and output the results to a new table in the new worksheet (from cell A2)
3. Move the worksheet to a new workbook for saving

My vba is average average at best, so I'm fine with points 1 & 3 but can't figure out part 2 and would appreciate some help.

Here is the code of the vba that works perfectly well when a table already exists, which is linked to the connection string:

```
Sub ODBC_RUN_REPORT()

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Dim jdeSystem As String
Dim jdecorelib As String
Dim jdeUDClib As String
Dim jdeGSClib As String
Dim jdeIBANlib As String
Dim jdeQUERYlib As String

Dim odbcConnection As odbcConnection
Dim connection_string As String

Dim commandtext1 As String
Dim commandtext2 As String
Dim commandtext3 As String
Dim commandtext4 As String
Dim commandtext5 As String
Dim commandtext6 As String
Dim commandtext7 As String
Dim commandtext8 As String
Dim commandtext9 As String
Dim commandtext10 As String

jdeSystem = Range("NR_CONSTR_ENV").Text
jdecorelib = Range("NR_CONSTR_CORE_LIB").Text
jdeUDClib = Range("NR_CONSTR_UDC_LIB").Text
jdeGSClib = Range("NR_CONSTR_GSC_LIB").Text
jdeIBANlib = Range("NR_CONSTR_IBAN_LIB").Text
jdeQUERYlib = Range("NR_CONSTR_QUERY_LIB").Text

connection_string = "ODBC;DRIVER={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};CONNTYPE=2;TRANSLATE=1;NAM=1;QRYSTGLMT=-1;PKG=QGPL/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512;LANGUAGEID=ENU;DFTPKGLIB=QGPL;DBQ=" + jdecorelib + " " + jdeUDClib + " " + jdeGSClib + " " + jdeIBANlib + " " + jdeQUERYlib + ";SYSTEM=" + jdeSystem + ";"

commandtext1 = Range("NR_CMD_TXTQ1").Text
commandtext2 = Range("NR_CMD_TXTQ2").Text
commandtext3 = Range("NR_CMD_TXTQ3").Text
commandtext4 = Range("NR_CMD_TXTQ4").Text
commandtext5 = Range("NR_CMD_TXTQ5").Text
commandtext6 = Range("NR_CMD_TXTQ6").Text
commandtext7 = Range("NR_CMD_TXTQ7").Text
commandtext8 = Range("NR_CMD_TXTQ8").Text
commandtext9 = Range("NR_CMD_TXTQ9").Text
commandtext10 = Range("NR_CMD_TXTQ10").Text

Set odbcConnection = ThisWorkbook.Connections("ODBC_RUN_REPORT").odbcConnection
odbcConnection.Connection = connection_string
odbcConnection.CommandText = commandtext1 + commandtext2 + commandtext3 + commandtext4 + commandtext5 + commandtext6 + commandtext7 + commandtext8 + commandtext9 + commandtext10

odbcConnection.Refresh
```

'NOTE - Everything below here is part of the vba code that works but it is not critical to keep for the version that will export to a new workbook.

```
Sheets("USER CONTROL").Select
Range("D14").Select

MsgBox "Report Refresh Complete"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Run a macro recording of you creating a new worksheet (not workbook yet!), and attaching it to some data from your database/data source. You will end up with something like this...

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "ODBC;DSN=xxx;Description=xxxx;UID=xxxx;;APP=Microsoft Office 2016;WSID=xxxx;DATABASE=xxxx;LANGUAGE=us_english" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = 0
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM dbo.myTable"
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_SPOT"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

This should get you the data into either a new or existing worksheet on your current workbook.

Now use something like this to copy/move the data or table into a new workbook...

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet

    '~~> Source/Input Workbook
    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> Set the relevant sheet from where you want to copy
    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Destination/Output Workbook
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

    With wbO
        '~~> Set the relevant sheet to where you want to paste
        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")

        '~~>. Save the file
        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Book2.xls", FileFormat:=56

        '~~> Copy the range
        wsI.Range("A1:B10").Copy

        '~~> Paste it in say Cell A1. Change as applicable
        wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
End Sub
```